# Remove all articles and other strings from a string using Go?

Tags: regex, string, go

Is there any method in Go or having regular expression that it will remove only the articles used in the string?

I have tried below code that will do it but it will also remove other words from the string I'm showing the code below:

```
 removalString := "This is a string"
 stringToRemove := []string{"a", "an", "the", "is"}
 for _, wordToRemove := range stringToRemove {
     removalString = strings.Replace(removalString, wordToRemove, "", -1)
 }
 space := regexp.MustCompile(`\s+`)
 trimedExtraSpaces := space.ReplaceAllString(removalString, " ")
 spacesCovertedtoDashes := strings.Replace(trimedExtraSpaces, " ", "-", -1)
 slug := strings.ToLower(spacesCovertedtoDashes)
 fmt.Println(slug)
```

**Edited**

[Play link](https://play.golang.org/p/f1uvuWW40TT)

In this It will remove the `is` which is used in the `this`.

The Expected output is `this-string`

Comment: If your request is for an existing implementation, that is off-topic, as resource requests are not allowed here.  If your question is how to improve or fix your current code, you need to be more specific: What problems are you facing? What help do you need?

Comment: Show examples of input and expected output and what fails.

Comment: Also note that "is" is not an article, it's a verb.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strings.Split`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) and [`strings.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) plus a loop for filtering and then building it together again:

```
removalString := "This is a string"
stringToRemove := []string{"a", "an", "the", "is"}
filteredStrings := make([]string, 0)
for _, w := range strings.Split(removalString, " ") {
    shouldAppend := true
    lowered := strings.ToLower(w)
    for _, w2 := range stringToRemove {
        if lowered == w2 {
            shouldAppend = false
            break
        }
    }
    if shouldAppend {
        filteredStrings = append(filteredStrings, lowered)
    }
}
resultString := strings.Join(filteredStrings, "-")
fmt.Printf(resultString)
```

Outpus:

```
this-string
Program exited.
```

Here you have the [live example](https://play.golang.org/p/Tle3Yc11-zM)

Answer (score 1):

My version just using regexp

Construct a regexp of the form '\ba\b|\ban\b|\bthe\b|\bis\b|' which will find
the words in the list that have "word boundaries" on both sides - so "This" is not matched

Second regexp reduces any spaces to dashes and makes multiple spaces a single dash

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    removalString := "This is a strange string"
    stringToRemove := []string{"a", "an", "the", "is"}

    var reg bytes.Buffer
    for _, x := range stringToRemove {
        reg.WriteString(`\b`) // word boundary
        reg.WriteString(x)
        reg.WriteString(`\b`)
        reg.WriteString(`|`) // alternation operator
    }
    regx := regexp.MustCompile(reg.String())
    slug := regx.ReplaceAllString(removalString, "")
    regx2 := regexp.MustCompile(` +`)
    slug = regx2.ReplaceAllString(slug, "-")

    fmt.Println(slug)
}
```